# How to give audio play file path in javascript for push notification?

Tags: javascript, audio

I have written following code in javascript to play audio file on receving push notification :

var my_media = new Media("http://www.talkingwav.com/answermachine/answer_01.wav");
                my_media.play();

Tried this also:

var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/soundw.mp3");
                my_media.play();
and tried this also:

var my_media = new Media("soundw.mp3");
                    my_media.play();

but nothing is working .Please tell me what exact path should I give?How can I play audio files using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

try using Audio instead. Like this:

`var my_media = new Audio("http://www.talkingwav.com/answermachine/answer_01.wav"); 
my_media.play();`

This works for me in latest Chrome.